# Как в WPF приложении получить путь к файлу, который инициировал запуск программы?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как при запуске программы передать в нее путь к файлу, который инициировал запуск программы? В консольном приложении это реализуется с помощью аргументов командной строки, а WPF как?

Comment: Уточните, вы хотите чтобы ваша программа появилась именно в меню выбора программы для открытия картинки "открыть с помощью.."? И задать формат передачи открываемого файла каким-то нестандартным способом? (Обычно ведь открываемый файл передается 1м аргументом коммандной строки)

Comment: @KromStern, нет, в меню выбора программа пока что не нужна. В WPF приложении нет вроде аргументов командной строки?

Comment: Сделайте необходимые уточнения в вопросе. Модель MVVM к вопросу не относится.

Comment: @KromStern, отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) доступен из любого места любого приложения.